# Shifting string with control shift input, same logic but different results

Tags: java

So say I have to shift the word banana 2 characters to the right, so that it becomes `nabana` - index 0 becomes 2, index 1 becomes 3 ... index 4 becomes 0 and index 5 becomes 1, etc.

So, the formula is:

```
(i + shiftControl) % length
```

I coded this in the following way:

```
public static String shiftString(String s, int n) {
    String newWord = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int index = (s.charAt(i) + n) % (s.length()); 
        newWord += s.charAt(index);
    }
    return newWord;
}
```

The issue is, I don't get `nabana`, I get `ananan` instead - I don't know where `b` went!

So I tried with `abcdef`, then I get `defabc`. It's only one behind. So I added `n+1` instead of `n`, then it works, but it doesn't for banana.

The logic is the same, but why don't I get the right answer for banana?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `newWord += s.charAt((i + n) % s.length());`? First calculate the index, then get the char at that index.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp no because if I do it that way I get out of index error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the formula is:

```
(i + shiftControl) % length
```

This is correct for determining the index of the character at position `i` in the original string in the shifted string. To use this you have to be able to index into the shifted string, i.e. use a `char` array:

```
public static String shiftString(String s, int n) {
    char[] newWord = new char[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int index = (i + n) % s.length();
        newWord[index] = s.charAt(i);
    }
    return String.valueOf(newWord);
}
```

However, if you want to build the shifted string from left to right you need to use the reverse formula, which is

```
(i + length - n) % length
```

Which we can use in your original method:

```
public static String shiftString(String s, int n) {
    String newWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int index = (i + s.length() - n) % s.length();
        newWord += s.charAt(index);
    }
    return newWord;
}
```

An alternative would be to just join together the right and left substrings in reverse order:

```
public static String shiftString(String s, int n) 
{
    return s.substring(s.length()-n) + s.substring(0, s.length()-n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the word banana by the position

```
  public static String shiftString(String str, int shift) {
    int len = str.length();
    char[] chars = new char[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      chars[(i + shift) % len] = str.charAt(i);
    }
    return new String(chars);
  }
```

, main

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(shiftString("banana", 1));
    System.out.println(shiftString("banana", 2));
    System.out.println(shiftString("banana", 3));
    System.out.println(shiftString("banana", 4));
    System.out.println(shiftString("banana", 5));
  }
```

, output

```
abanan
nabana
anaban
nanaba
ananab
```

Answer (score 0):

change the fourth line to:

```
int index = (i + n) % (s.length()-n);
```

Comment: why? I'm not sure why